# BrainTree Recurring Bill: How to store a customer in the Vault

Tags: ruby, braintree, recurring-billing

I'm trying to implement a Recurring Bill in my application by using BrainTree. In BrainTree's documentation, to create a Subscription, it requires that the customer has to be stored in the Vault, but the option :store_in_vault is only available for Transaction but I couldn't find any way to create a customer stored in the Vault from my application. I tend to add a Transaction with amount 0$ to the Vault then create the Subscription. 
Is there any other possibility to do this more appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

To create a customer stored in the Vault, use [`Customer.create`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/ruby#customer-with-a-payment-method), passing in the nonce from your client as the `payment_method_nonce` parameter. This will create a `Customer` as well as a `PaymentMethod`.

Afterwards call [`Subscription.create`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby) using the `payment_method_token` and the `plan_id`.